# My magento login not working

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have tried many options but still not working please any body who can fix it. my username and password both are correct please. my back end is working fine but the front end login is not working.
I tried editing and commenting code in varien.php. i tried http as no in configurations setting
still not working and giving invalid username password error. but the credentials are correct.

Comment: which magento version are u using ?

Comment: it is 1.9.1.0 version

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with `form-key`

1. Go to `app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and `template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` and under
2. Find: `<ul class=”form-list”>`
3. And paste this right after the code above the following:

   `<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo`     `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />`

Repeat above for `app/design/frontend/Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`

Comment: i dont have this path app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/customer/form/login.phtml

Comment: i have this path app/design/frontend/Your-package]/[Your-theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml and i changed in it but its not working

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9 check this

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

1. Login to admin.
2. Navigate to Admin-> System-> Configuration-> Customer-> Customer
   Configuration-> Share Customer Accounts
3. Set **Share Customer Accounts** To Global

Make sure to take backup if you are working with production server.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: is there any other way?